# If the sides of $\triangle ABC$ are $a$, $b$, $c$ (with $a$ opposite $A$), then can we say $\frac{a}{a+b+c}=\frac{A}{180}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

> If we know all three sides of a triangle, say $a=3,b=4,c=5$, then can we know their corresponding angles by the following formula?
>
> $$\frac{a}{a+b+c} = \frac{A}{180}$$ where $A$ is the angle across from the side with length $a=3$. Why or why not?

A student asked me this today while we were using the law of cosines to solve $SSS$ triangles and I didn't have a good answer.

Comment: We have $\hat C=90^\circ$ in this special case. Is your formula verified?!

Comment: Consider a $45^\circ$-$45^\circ$-$90^\circ$ triangle or a $30^\circ$-$60^\circ$-$90^\circ$ triangle.

Comment: So this only holds in special cases?? Anyone understand why it does not generalize?

Comment: Sides and angles aren't linearly related.  You don't double a length of a side by doubling an angle.  There's no reason it *should* work.  cosider a right angle an $60$ regree angle you can increase the angle $60$ to anything less than $90$  but you can't increase it to $90$ or more.  So the angle can only increase by less than $50\%$.  However the side can increase unlimitedly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the sine law, you have
$$\frac{a}{\sin A}=\frac{b}{\sin B}=\frac{c}{\sin C}=\frac{a+b+c}{\sin A+\sin B+\sin C}$$
where the last equality is obtained by summing the numerators and denominators. This implies that
$$\frac{a}{a+b+c}=\frac{\sin A}{\sin A+\sin B+\sin C}$$
So if you want to use the formula you wrote, it would have to be true that
$$\frac{\sin A}{\sin A+\sin B+\sin C} = \frac{A}{180} $$
This will be true for equilateral triangles and some degenerate cases such as $A=0$. In general, I'm not sure there are any other angles of a triangle satisfying the relation. Also, for the solutions of the equation, it does matter whether $A$ is in radians or degrees.

Comment: Well, there is an equilateral triangle.  Kinda wimpy, but existing.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Yes, thanks for pointing out.